# Set element's height to <body>'s width and its width to <body>'s height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want `.container`'s *height* to be set dynamically to `<body>`'s *width* and its *height* to `<body>`'s *width*, and it should change when the window is resized.

I want this because I'm trying to make a CSS only horizontally scrolling page by rotating the `.container' -90 degrees and its contents 90 degrees a la http://jsfiddle.net/3cetk351/.

The container currently has 100% height & width but once it's rotated via CSS, it retains its inherited dimensions and does not stretch to browser window size which I suppose is only logical.

I don't know much of javascript other than to change values in jquery plugins but I assume it's possible using js to dynamically alter `.container`'s *height* and *width* to `<body>`'s computed *width* and *height* respectively.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/ZaLHM/

Comment: What you most likely want is, [http://api.jquery.com/resize/](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). Which is the `.resize()` event

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Like I said, I'm a total js noob and don't know how to use it :/, I'd appreciate it if you could make a demo.

Comment: [A very rough draft - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5abF/) could work something like that.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for taking the time to make the demo, but Matt's got the answer that works best for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

```
var supportsOrientationChange = 'onorientationchange' in window, orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize';

var $containment = document.getElementsByClassName('containment')[0];

$containment.style.width = window.innerHeight + 'px';
$containment.style.height = window.innerWidth + 'px';

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    $containment.style.width = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    $containment.style.height = window.innerWidth + 'px';
}, false);
```

Here's a fork of your pen here: http://codepen.io/stowball/pen/AIbHn

Comment: Using this seems to give the container the height and width of the window though and not the `<body>`'s. Nevertheless, this is excellent. Thanks Matt!

Here's the result with only the necessary element in html http://dabblet.com/gist/6055177.